# Submit PDF form fields (Acrobat) to HTTP Post using Application/JSON

Tags: json, forms, pdf, sharepoint, acrobat

**Background:**

1. I have created a Microsoft Sharepoint list, with two columns (forename, surname).
2. I have created a Adobe Acrobat PDF form, with two fields (forename, surname) and a submit button.
3. I have used MS Power Automate (aka MS Flow) to create an automation process, that `when a HTTP Request is received`, to POST fields from the PDF into the SharePoint list (this uses JSON request schema).

**Problem:**

When I fill out the form in the PDF and click submit, the SharePoint list is populated - however, the fields are blank. So the connection works, but the data is not being carried over.

When I create a HTML form and submit the form, using `application/json` content type, the data is transferred. See this tutorial that explains how this works: [YouTube Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4wRDq5bQl4)

So... my question is - how to I set the content type as `application/json` in Adobe Acrobat for PDF forms? Or is there something else I'm doing wrong?

Below is a paste of the JSON I have used in the flow, within 'When a HTTP request is received' (Request Body JSON Schema):

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "forename": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "surname": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: can you share the flow where pdf form data is sent upon submit button click?

Comment: You can see the [Flow here](https://imgur.com/T3uCxvZ)

Comment: The PDF specification only knows 4 types of form data submissions, (A) full PDF, (B) XFDF of form, (C) FDF of form, and (D) HTML Form.

Comment: @mkl - Rather than using `submit a form` action, what if I used `run a JavaScript` action instead? Could this potentially work?

Comment: @MuhammadMuradHaider See this link for more info: https://habeebstech.wordpress.com/2020/03/03/transfer-data-from-acrobat-pdf-form-submission-to-sharepoint-list-using-a-power-automate-flow/  But thank you for your help in trying to get this fixed.

Comment: great read HY!.. Glad that you figured it out